# Sharing Quiz Results on Facebook

Tags: html, facebook-share

I've a javascript quiz on a web page and I would like to have an option for the user to share their result to Facebook once the quiz is over. The final result will be something like this(depending on the user) "Hey I participated and got 10 points.....".

I want an option to share this final result + url of the web page. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you store the score in a variable as `var score=10;`

Then, use the below

```
function share(score){
     var desc=encodeURIComponent("Hey, I scored "+score+" in a quiz");
    window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=www.yoursite.com&description="+desc);
}
```

And call the function as

```
 share(10);
```

Replace the `10` with the score

Comment: Facebook seems to block this method